# string search C++

Tags: c++, string, search

I currently work with PLY files. I´m able to load it, and save to string array. Next I have to search keywords. For example, somewhere in text is line 'element vertex 8'. I can find the line, but how to get the number from it?

```
std::fstream cube2;
cube2.open(argv[1],std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);

string line;
string line2[1000] = {};
int index = 0;

while (getline(cube2,line))
{           
    line2[index] = line;
    index++;
}
cube2.close();
```

Comment: if you use `c++11` you can use `<regex>` library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming by 'number' you mean find the index of this substring inside your original string?

Use:

```
    #include <string.h>

    std::string substr = "element vertex 8";
    size_t index_of_substring = line2.find(substr);

    if (index_of_substring!=std::string::npos)
        std::cout << "Found my substring " << substr << " at index " << index_of_substring" << '\n';
```

Assuming that `line2` is the string to be searched;
the `find` function of the `std::string` library returns the position of the first character of the substring that was found in your original string that was searched.

Comment: Thank you! Can I index substring in array directly, or I have use another string forit?
strin MyArray[] = {};
command: cout << MyArray[0], will take first array, but I want to index first character of that array.

Comment: Your array is of `string` type so it should work directly. The `find` function is a `string` class function, so as long as your data type is a string, whether it is initialised as an array or not, it should still work. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) for more information.

Is `MyArray` an array of arrays? If so `MyArray[0]` will return you the first array in that array. Accessing any elements in _this_ array is the same: `MyArray[0][0]` will return you the first character in the first array of `MyArray`.